# Xubuntu freezes forcing me to power cycle

Tags: drivers, 16.04, xubuntu, google-chrome

I just installed Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS as a dual boot on my Dell Inspiron 11-3157. It appears to crash whenever I at least have Google Chrome open and other apps such as Spotify. I have tried switching to the proprietary graphics card but the freezing still occurs.

I also upgraded my BIOS but the issue still occurs on xubuntu.

Here is the trouble shooting data:

- [lspci](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a306943cd372193e3e190acb12528361)
- [swap/ memory- BIOS has been updated to 1.2.1](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/82112725c4f6480893a4c1ab90c7e345)

free:

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      3956448      558052     2791756       91836      606640     3052820
Swap:     4103676        0        4103676
```

swapon:

> NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
>
> /dev/dm-0 partition 3.9G   0B   -1

mcelog:

```
Memory errors
SOCKET 1 CHANNEL 4 DIMM 0
DMI_NAME "A1_DIMM0" DMI_LOCATION "A1_BANK0"
corrected memory errors:
    0 total
    0 in 24h
uncorrected memory errors:
    0 total
    0 in 24h
```

More System Info:

```
description: Portable Computer
product: Inspiron 11-3157 (06CA)
vendor: Dell Inc.
version: 1.2.1
serial: B2C6982
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=06CA uuid=44454C4C-3200-1043-8036-C2C04F393832
```

intel-microcode:

```
[    1.865596] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x406c3, pf=0x1, revision=0x33c
[    1.865758] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x406c3, pf=0x1, revision=0x33c
[    1.865832] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x406c3, pf=0x1, revision=0x33c
[    1.865847] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x406c3, pf=0x1, revision=0x33c
[    1.866512] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01
```

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap?

Comment: @heynnema Here is my swap and memory info: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/82112725c4f6480893a4c1ab90c7e345

Comment: @Terrance I never had these symptoms when I just had vanilla Windows 10 on my laptop. I have only been using this Xubuntu dual boot for a day and have yet to test out if this issue is occurring on my windows partition

Comment: Thanks for the info. It didn't include the swap info that I needed. In terminal, give me the output of `swapon` and `free`. Also I couldn't find your model at the Dell web site. I wanted to check for BIOS updates. I need the service tag # to find it... or you can look yourself... to check for BIOS updates.

Comment: ps: best I can tell the latest BIOS is 1.2.1 and it looks like you may have 1.1.13... so update your BIOS asap. Use the service tag # to find the BIOS update download file.

Comment: @heynnema I updated my BIOS to 1.2.1 (see above) but it still froze after I was testing Chrome and opening a Spotify client. I have also added output from swapon and free. FWIW- I am not using Chrome and sticking to Mozilla to see if it freezes again. Thanks for helping!

Comment: While using Chrome, leave a `terminal` window open, and use the `free` command occasionally, and monitor the `used` and `free` space for both mem and swap.

Comment: @heynnema I ran a browser testing app and repeatedely ran __free__ and got this output around the time my OS freezed again: http://imgur.com/a/HG360

Comment: The swapon/free numbers look ok. Hum, you could review `more /var/log/syslog` or `more /var/log/syslog.1` around the time of the freeze and see if you can find something more to give us a clue.

Comment: @heynnema  I froze it again at around 16:02 and have produced a [syslog](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8ec5dfb89834b0e4a1b121124637f473). Upon analysis it looks like it may have to do with ecryptfs starting around 15:59... – operationcwl

Comment: Your processor is a Celeron, yes? Maybe it just can't handle disk encryption. You encrypted it yourself, yes? It didn't come that way? What did you see in syslog?

Comment: @heynnema Yes it's a Celeron. I ticked 'encrypt Home folder' when creating my initial admin account. This is the syslog: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8ec5dfb89834b0e4a1b121124637f473

Comment: Interesting syslog. You might try installing `intel-microcode` and we can see if it updates your processors. In `terminal`, type `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`. Reboot. In `terminal` again, type `dmesg | grep microcode` to see it in action.

Comment: @heynnema Here's the output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/20bce1c6948ad84f5bc77bb52bb22064

Comment: Your processors were already up to date! What are you going to do about encryption? Reinstall Xubuntu?